# Creating a DLL that uses another DLL and access using JNI

Tags: c++, dll, java-native-interface

I'm facing a problem when I try to use JNI with a DLL that I created.

I created a DLL called InfraredTest.dll. This dll references to another one, called RedRat.dll.
When I try to use a function inside the InfraredTest.dll that uses the RedRat.dll function, then I receive a fatal error from JVM.

Observations:
1 - I already tested the RedRat.dll link, creating InfraRedTest.exe and it works fine with the same code.
2 - I already tested the InfraRedTest.dll with JNI without the RedRat.dll call and also works fine.

I can see that the problem is that the RedRat.dll is not being found. I've put in the same place that the first DLL and also received an JVM crash.

Here is the code:

```
#include "IRWrapper.h"  
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace RedRat;
using namespace RedRat::RedRat3;
using namespace RedRat::RedRat3::USB;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL   
Java_HelloWorld_displayHelloWorld(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)  
{  
    printf(" --- Calling IRWrapper.dll --- \n");

    array<LocationInfo^>^ rr3Li = RedRat3USBImpl::FindRedRat3s();
    if (rr3Li->Length == 0)
    {
        printf("No RedRats found.");
    }   else {
        printf("Found: %d devices.\n",rr3Li->Length);
    }
    return;  
}
```

Comment: Is the source code you're showing here the source code for the DLL you _can_ load or the one you _can't_? How are you attempting to _load_ the DLL you can't load -- explicitly somehow or implicitly by load-time imports in the DLL you _can_ load? How did you _link_ the DLL you _can_ load? Where are the corresponding Java definitions?

Comment: I forgot to say. I'm using VC2008. So the DLL is referenced. This exactly code works when I compile a EXE and change the dysplayHelloWorld to main.

Comment: Have you tried to use `System.load("/path/to/RedRat.dll")` to "preload" it?

Comment: Yes I did. I first tried System.loadLibrary, them I changed to just load. Both resulted the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `InfraredTest.dll` might be linked improperly against `RedRat.lib`. I don't see the most important test scenario in your observations: simulating the whole calling chain. Have `CallingTheSameFunctionsLikeJava.exe`, which calls `InfraredTest.dll` and that calls `RedRat.dll`. With your existing tests, you always test only one chain link. I bet that once this testing exe works correctly, JNI won't have a problem anymore too. If you still have problems with the Java-simulated exe, post the problem again, but don't tag with `JNI`.

Comment: I'm using VC2008 and referencing the dll. I don't have a RedRat.lib just the DLL. This code works when generates a EXE and also the RedRat.dll is in the same lvl that the exe.

Comment: Unless you are doing dynamic function lookup (aka DLL lazy loading), you do have a lib. It's called [import library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries). Look around your project. And i still don't know whether you tried doing EXE instead of Java (calling all the way through InfraredTest to RedRat). You are talking only about EXE instead of InfraredTest (calling only RedRat).

Comment: Unfortunatetly I don't have a lib for the RedRat dll. This is the only way to access the functions of the RedRat hardware.

Comment: An about the EXE. Yes it worked. I've created first a test, the exe file. So I created another project (DLL) using the same algorithm but I changed what I should to work with JNI. The biggest problem is that the SDK of this hardware is only accessible loading they DLL. I can work with the exe using java process but this is exactly what I want to avoid in order to make the system more stable.

Comment: Here's the code: `void main (void) 
{
 array<LocationInfo^>^ rr3Li = RedRat3USBImpl::FindRedRat3s();
 if (rr3Li->Length == 0) {
  printf("No RedRats found.");
 } else {
  printf("Found: %d devices.\n",rr3Li->Length);
 }
}`

Comment: Tell me once more please: do you have an `exe` which calls the JNI-formatted functions exported from `InfraredTest.dll`, while `InfraredTest.dll` also calls *successfuly* `RedRat.dll` ?

Comment: No. This I don't have. What I have is: 1 exe with the function above that uses the `RedRat.dll` successfuly. After this, I created a DLL project that calls exactly as the exe the `RedRat.dll` and uses the same algorithm but instead of the main it is a JNI call. If I just put a prinf and calls in using java, it appears. If I put above the printf anything of the RedRat.dll then it crashes. But I can try create another EXE that calls the new `Infrared.dll` an see if works.